# Java Convert long value to date with exact precision of nano seconds

Tags: java

The date in database is `2012-03-20 12:24:34.123456`. We need to display it in long format.so, we used `getTime()` method. But when we are converting back to date again, the nano seconds are not matching exact precision. The date after conversion is `2012-03-20 12:24:34.123`. last 456 is missing. any one help to get exact date with nano seconds.

Comment: Date for a discussion of slight discrepancies that may arise between "computer time" and coordinated universal time (UTC).

Comment: While there's no "wall clock" value available that returns nanosecond precision (the System.timeNano value isn't tied to "wall clock" time), you can, of course, *format* a timestamp with more than 3 digits of subsecond data.  That's simply a matter of using the correct format specifier.

Comment: can u give more details? like for formatting timestamp with more than 3 digits.

Comment: Which database, and which JDBC library?

Comment: Six digits of fractional second is microsecond, not nanoseconds. [Nanoseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) would be nine digits.

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc
java.util.Date, getTime(), returns the number of **milliseconds** since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object. 456 is missing because is less than millisecond, is **microseconds**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTimestamp()` instead of `getTime()`. The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object returned, when treated like a `java.util.Date`, has integer seconds. By calling `getNanos()` on it, you can get the fractional seconds in nanoseconds.

Comment: getNanos will return 123000. not exact value of nano seconds.

Comment: Do you mean 123000000, or 123456000? `getNanos` should return 9 digits. I tested with PostgreSQL's JDBC3 driver and it gave me 6 digits after the decimal point, which in your question seems to be the precision you say your database stores.